# how to delete native dialer app from AOSP apps completly

Tags: android, android-source

I want that native Dialer apps should be removed from AOSP apps. But any how i did not succeeded. I have deleted the /dialer from telephony.mk and build again. But it still display the dialer app on screen.
I also try make clean before build.

Comment: Can you explain us why a geneal computing question has been posted on a **programming** specific Q&A site?

Comment: ok. Because it require to change .mk file.  and then build.  and i dont get any idea how to achive it. Please provide me another link ,where i can ask?

Comment: xda forum? android enthusiasts? GOOGLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the dialer on android is actually a part of Contacts app, so you should modify Contacts instead.